# Does a(a+1)(a+2)-1=b²+2=10c+3 have solutions over natural numbers? If yes, how many?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations

It is a question from the math olympiad I was participating in that happened like a month ago. The provided solution turned out to be wrong.

It isn't the question itself, but the solution basically comes to it:

If it doesn't have any solutions, the answer should be 8.

If it has 5 or more, then it should be 5.

If it's something between 1 and 4 then it'd be pretty weird ngl.

The answer considered correct was 8 but mine was 5 and it got marks as if it was correct. Which is weird af.

Comment: What is ngl? Is this related to the software `Mathematica` or did you want to ask this on the [`maths`](https://math.stackexchange.com/) site?

Comment: Ah no, it's "not gonna lie", sorry for the confusion. I just don't expect it to have this few solutions. In reality, 1-2 solutions would result the answer of 7, and 3-4 the answer of 6.

Comment: What I meant by "find solutions over integers" is "find such integer triplets of a, b, and c that would make corresponding expressions equal". So a, b, and c should all be integers. It is a diophantine problem.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I should've said "natural numbers" since it shouldn't be negative or 0.

Comment: Are your equations correct? So what are those five solutions that your answer was `5`?

Comment: I do not understand the question, but `FindInstance` does not find any solution over $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @azerbajdzan I do not actually have any. I couldn't find them but it kinda felt like there should be solutions, so I answered 5 and for some reason got marks as if I answered 8.

Comment: @mattiav27 okay, so probably there is none. Then it's weird that it thought that my answer is correct. Also, why is there no integer solutions?